# pgvector with custom filter

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase, pgvector

hi how can I add a custom filter to a sql function in a supabase database that uses pgvector to store embeddings.

```
create table documents (
  id bigserial primary key,
  content text,
  embedding vector(1536),
custom_id text // Custom id for each company
);
```

Something like this:

```
create or replace function match_documents (
  query_embedding vector(1536),
  match_threshold float,
  match_count int,
  custom_id text
)
returns table (
  id bigint,
  content text,
  similarity float
)
language sql stable
as $$
  select
    documents.id,
    documents.content,
    1 - (documents.embedding <=> query_embedding) as similarity
  from documents
  where documents.custom_id == custom_id
  order by similarity desc
  limit match_count;
$$;
```

The problem with this function is that if I ask for information about x custom_id, it responds with data from all the documents, it does not respect the where. I need to filter the documents by custom_id before checking the embedding similarity.

Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is your `where` clause is effective `1=1`; which is true for every row. The right operand (`custom_id`) is not qualified within a table reference. Postgres therefore assumes you are referring to the column `custom_id` within the table. You can correct this 2 ways: 1. Use a different parameter name than the column name. A common convention being to prefix parameters with `p_`; so `p_custom_id`.  2. Fully qualify the reference to `match_documents.custom_id`. This all assumes `==` is a typo as Postgres has no such operator, it just uses `=`.

Comment: Thanks, so first I order the documents like  this "where documents.custom_id = match_documents.custom_id", and then I add all the vector logic, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems. First, Postgres uses `=`, and not `==` for equality checks. Second, since there is a column named `custom_id` and a parameter of the function also named `custom_id`, you need to disambiguate these two. You can do so by adding function name and a dot, in this case `match_documents.`, before the `custom_id` in the filter.

```sql
create or replace function match_documents (
  query_embedding vector(1536),
  match_threshold float,
  match_count int,
  custom_id text
)
returns table (
  id bigint,
  content text,
  similarity float
)
language sql stable
as $$
  select
    documents.id,
    documents.content,
    1 - (documents.embedding <=> query_embedding) as similarity
  from documents
  where documents.custom_id = match_documents.custom_id
  order by similarity desc
  limit match_count;
$$;
```